# Product of a compact topological space and a singleton in another topological space is compact proof

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

It's before we prove that 'Product of two compact sets is compact'. There are topological spaces $X$(which is compact), $Y$ and the product topology on $X \times Y$ is given by the subbase $U \times V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$. Pick an element $\bullet \in Y$. Let $S$ be an open cover of $X \times \{\bullet\}$. Then $\pi_1(S)$ is an open cover of $X$ so there is a finite subcover then pick one $A_n$ from $S$ corresponding to each $\pi_1(A_n)$ but I think it may not cover $X \times \{\bullet\}$. How to complete the proof? For example let $Y$ be a $T_1$ space and pick another element $\bullet\bullet \in Y$. There exists an open set $W$ containing $\bullet\bullet$ but not
 $\bullet$. Lets construct an open cover of $X \times \{\bullet\}$
$$S \cup \{B \times W \mid B \in \pi_1(S)\}$$
Now we can apply this open cover to upper proof, and when we are picking $A_n$ from $S \cup \{B \times W \mid B \in \pi_1(S)\}$ corresponding to each $\pi_1(A_n)$, we may pick all the sets from $\{B \times W \mid B \in \pi_1(S)\}$ so in fact it doesn't cover $X \times \{\bullet\}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations of the sentence "Let $S$ be an open cover of $X \times \{\bullet\}$":

1. Let $S$ be a collection of open subsets of $X \times Y$ which cover $X \times \{\bullet\}$. In this case, you must be careful how you proceed, for the reason that you have observed.
2. Let $S$ be a collection of open subsets of $X \times \{\bullet\}$ which cover $X \times \{\bullet\}$, where $X \times \{\bullet\}$ is given the subspace topology of $X \times Y$. In this case, you can simply observe that $\pi_1: X \times \{\bullet\} \to X$ is a homeomorphism, and the proof you've described works perfectly.

In the case that you are using version 1, observe that the intersection of an open subset of $X \times Y$ with $X \times \{\bullet\}$ forms an open subset of $X \times \{\bullet\}$, which projects under $\pi_1$. onto an open subset of $X$.

Comment: Why is it an open subset? Perhaps from compactness of $X$? If we intersect an open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a line $\mathbb{R} \times \{\bullet\}$ it results in something like an open interval but it is not an open set of course. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Comment: Actually there exists a closed square centered at the origin containing the open disk so we can replace $\mathbb{R}$ with a closed interval $I$.

Comment: @Ris it is literally the definition of the subspace topology that an open subset of $X \times Y$ intersected with $X \times \{\bullet\}$ is an open subset of $X \times \{\bullet\}$.

Comment: If you want to avoid using the subspace topology, just prove that $\pi_1(U \cap X \times \{\bullet\}) \subset X$ is open for $U \subset X \times Y$ open.

Comment: Oh I thought that it meant to be the subset which is open in $X \times Y$. Does the term "open subset of $A$" always refer to an open set of the subspace topology on $A$? I was always confused of that.

Comment: @Ris it's ambiguous.